# Optimal layout of 3 text divs for print

Tags: html, css, printing, typesetting

I am writing a book made of about 500 pages, where each page contains up to 3 sections, "a" "b" and "c". In each page, the content length of each section is different: in page 1, for example, there may be a long "a", no "b", and a short "c"; In page 2, there may be a medium "a", a short "b", and a long "c", etc.

The contents of each section in each page are given in HTML format.

I would like to layout the sections on the page, so that the page area is used efficiently. Here is an example of a NON efficient layout, that I want to prevent:

```
aaa bbb ccc
aaa     ccc
aaa     ccc
        ccc
        ccc
```

As you can see, there is a lot of wasted area.

Initially, I tried to control the column widths according to the content length, for example:

```
aaa b ccccc
aaa b ccccc
aaa b ccccc
```

This is more efficient, however, column "b" is too narrow and difficult to read.

Another thing I tried is to keep the width constant, but use "float" layout. For example, suppose I only have columns "a" and "b":

```
aaa bbb 
aaaaaa
```

If I had only two columns, this could be quite simple:

- If a is much longer than b, then make b float right;
- If b is much longer than a, then make a float left;
- If they are approximately the same length, then make them two adjacent columns.

However, this becomes much more complicated when there are 3 columns, as there are many possible combinations.

Is there a general solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at jQuery [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Might not be what you're exactly looking for, but I imagine it might be of help.

Comment: +1 for the potentially useful plugin. However, it seems that the width of each div should be fixed in advance. This is not good for me, because sometimes there are only 1 or 2 divs, so their width should change according to their content so that they span the entire page.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Indeed, that might be an issue. Will try to come up with something better.

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi Well, there's an algorithmic approach to this. Would you be interested in such an approach?